# How many Salvage droid levels are there?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

It looks like there might be two levels you can unlock by sending out salvage droids. Am I correct in thinking this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are 2 levels per planet (I can confirm 3 of them personally, and other threads have confirmed the others):

Endor: Endor Arms (residential) & Ewok Adventure (recreation)
Kashyyyk: Wookie Arms (residential) & Kashyyyk Shack (retail)
Csilla: Csilla Apts (residential) & Chiss HSP (service)

There is a new imperial level, Overbridge, but thus far I haven't seen anyone with solid info on how to unlock it.